# Parted equivalent of sfdisk -d

Tags: linux, parted

I have to dump all my GPT partitions from one drive to another.
The MBR equivalent would be `sfdisk -d`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [GPT fdisk](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/):

```
[I] sys-apps/gptfdisk
     Available versions:  0.6.13 (~)0.7.2 (~)0.8.0
     Installed versions:  0.8.0(10:58:25 PM 10/12/2011)
     Homepage:            http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/
     Description:         gdisk - GPT partition table manipulator for Linux
```

Assuming that you want to dump partition table from `sda` to `sdb`, try this:

```
sgdisk -R=/dev/sdb /dev/sda
```

**Pay attention to the order, don't revert.**

Comment: I just wanted to add, that `-R` is the shorthand version of `--replicate` and specifies the target device.